# How to design two tables with aggregation relationship in ios core data?

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design, xcode6

This question might be more related to database design, but I want to use it in iphone specially in xcode 6, core data model. I have 2 classes with following relationship.

`Journey` 1 ---->  1..* `Coordinates`

So each `journey` can have 1 to many `coordinates`.
As you can see in following picture I have one field in `journey` called `id` and one field in `coordinate` called `journeyId`.

[image]

I do not know this design is perfect or not. Later I want to fetch each Journey with its Coordinates. Now the `journey` and `coordinates` looks like this:

[image]

[image]

My question is, how to define a `NSPredicate` to fetch every `journey` with its related `coordinate`/s? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

So first I observe in your CoreData model, you have indicated that you will only have 1 Coordinate -- you should see a double arrowhead.   Select the arrow in the CoreData Editor, and check the Data Model Inspector in the right toolbar 
[image: model change]

```
@interface Journey : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *journeyName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *journeyId;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *coordinates;  // NSSet of Coordinates
@end
```

Note that Collections one to many relationships are un-ordered sets - you you may need to include a sort index on your coordinates objects.

So fetching the data would be done like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Journey" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

// results now contains a sorted (by name) of Journey -- and each journey has a collection (unsorted) -- which you can sort by an index added at insertion time.
```